# from where did the self.request come from?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Lately I was learning Django and Django rest framework from the official docs and i stumbled upon a method defined inside the `GenericAPIView` named `get_queryset`. Till now everything is fine
but i was lost when he override this latter
the code is as follow:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return user.accounts.all()
```

My question is simple, the request is not defined in the method's argument
so where did it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a member of the `View` parent class. The class that this method is inside of will inherit from `View` or a child class of `View`. Something like:

```
class YourView(View):
    . . .
```

By inheriting from `View`, it inherits behaviors as well, like the `setup` function that's called that populates that attribute.

You may want to review classes and inheritance before continuing with Django. Django makes quite extensive use of inheritance and some advanced class features like metaclasses.

Comment: I know about inheritence but when I was searching for this member it didn't occur to me to look for it in the View class, I was just looking inside the APIView class
anyway thanks for your clarification